# Setting column types while reading csv with pandas

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, pandas, types

Trying to read **csv** file into ***pandas*** dataframe with the following formatting

```
dp = pd.read_csv('products.csv', header = 0,  dtype = {'name': str,'review': str,
                                                      'rating': int,'word_count': dict}, engine = 'c')
print dp.shape
for col in dp.columns:
    print 'column', col,':', type(col[0])
print type(dp['rating'][0])
dp.head(3)
```

This is the output:

```
(183531, 4)
column name : <type 'str'>
column review : <type 'str'>
column rating : <type 'str'>
column word_count : <type 'str'>
<type 'numpy.int64'>
```

[image]

I can sort of understand that ***pandas*** might be finding it difficult to convert a string representation of a dictionary into a dictionary given [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/converting-a-string-to-dictionary) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675942/converting-string-to-dict?lq=1). But how can the content of the "rating" column be both str and numpy.int64???

By the way, tweaks like not specifying an engine or header do not change anything.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your loop you are doing:

```
for col in dp.columns:
    print 'column', col,':', type(col[0])
```

and you are correctly seeing `str` as the output everywhere because `col[0]` is the first letter of the name of the column, which is a string.

For example, if you run this loop:

```
for col in dp.columns:
    print 'column', col,':', col[0]
```

you will see the first letter of the string of each column name is printed out  - this is what `col[0]` is.

Your loop only iterates on the *column names*, not on the *series data*.

What you really want is to check the type of each column's data (not its header or part of its header) in a loop.

So do this instead to get the types of the column data (non-header data):

```
for col in dp.columns:
    print 'column', col,':', type(dp[col][0])
```

This is similar to what you did when printing the type of the `rating` column separately.

Comment: Thanks, that was a slip on my part :)  I am choosing this as the accepted answer because it is a direct response to my question.

Comment: I guess it was a typo, sometimes hard to detect when focused on the code ;)

Answer (score 6):

Use:

```
dp.info()
```

to see the datatypes of the columns. `dp.columns` refers to the column header names, which are strings.

Comment: Another shortcut I missed in the very dense pandas documentation--thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check this one first: [Pandas: change data type of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/pandas-change-data-type-of-columns)

when google `pandas dataframe column type`, it's on the top 5 answers.

Comment: Thank you, that is useful.  I wish there were also a discussion of how to force conversion into dict type, as well (if there is one).

Comment: I don't think that is an answer to this question though - the question requires setting a column type *during* the read_csv process.  Doing it post fact may be highly undesirable in a given use case.   Good link though.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `read_table` with delimiter as `","` along with `literal_eval` as functions for converting values in the concerned columns.

```
recipes = pd.read_table("\\souravD\\PP_recipes.csv", sep=r',',
                      names=["id", "i", "name_tokens", "ingredient_tokens", "steps_tokens", "techniques","calorie_level","ingredient_ids"],
                      converters = {'name_tokens' : literal_eval,
                                    'ingredient_tokens' : literal_eval,
                                    'steps_tokens' : literal_eval,
                                    'techniques' : literal_eval,
                                    'ingredient_ids' : literal_eval},header=0)
```

[image: image of recipes dataframe after changing datatype]