# Changing Dtypes from int64 to string does not work

Tags: python, pandas, types

I have a dataframe with multiple columns like so

```
SE#    Name       Industry Code  Industry 
12345  Tom Jerry  923            Travel
```

The SE# is int64 and Industry Code is int64, the rest are Objects.

I used

```
df.astype(str)
```

and the column dtypes changes to objects but when I saved the file as a csv and then read that file back in, the data types reset to int64. Please advise on how to make sure that the datatypes remain as objects

The end goal is that I will be reading the CSV file into a SQL database and when I do so the SE Column appears as an int.

Thanks!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting column types while reading csv with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195485/setting-column-types-while-reading-csv-with-pandas)

Comment: The CSV file is not going to be read in by python - i will be importing the file into a SQL DB and so the SE column reverts to an int

Comment: What's the schema of the table you're reading the data into?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with pandas. If you read the csv into a SQL database then the type is determined by the table definition. If you're going to use [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) you can specify the type with the `dtype` parameter.

Comment: Normally `to_csv` does not quote strings.  So the string `"3"` will write the same as numeric `3`.  You can change that with the `quoting` parameter.  But that doesn't change how (default) `pd.read_csv` handles number-like strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pickle format for saving data frame
To save data frame as pickle use

```
df.to_pickle('your_file_name.pkl')
```

and to retrieve from the file using

```
pd.read_pickle('your_file_name.pkl')
```

Comment: The data is written to a CSV, and then read into a database. Databases don't know pickle ...

Answer (score 0):

you can explicitly mention  while read csv  file  like  this,

```
    df=pd.read_csv(  filename   ,  dtypes ={  'SE' : str  })
```